# camel: split the message into multiple processing paths

Tags: apache-camel

My input message:

```
<file>
   <node1>
    ...
   </node1>
   .....
   <node10>
   .....
   </node10>
</file>
```

I want to:

1. Process the whole file using stylesheet and output to Dest A
2. For a few elements in the file (say, node1, node3 and node7) I want to extract them and output the content of each individually to Dest B

I know how to process the file using stylesheet but I'm at a loss how to do the other, let alone combine them together.
I'm looking for something like:

```
from(direct:start).magic_split(
 to("xslt:mysheet").to("destA"),
 setBody(xpath("//node1").to("destB"),
 setBody(xpath("//node3").to("destB"),
 setBody(xpath("//node7").to("destB"),
 ).transform(constant(responseOK);
```

Comment: I'm thinking custom splitter bean...

Answer (score 0):

if you can split the XML, then each node is put in it's own exchange, if you can identify the node after it is split, then you can use a Content Based Router to route the exchange to the appropriate destination.  This might require a custom splitter bean, or you might be able to do it from xpath if the nodes are named nodeX where X is a number.

Comment: I don't think that would wuite give me what I want. First, the first processing path (customBean1 below) needs the whole XML, transformed. The second path (customBean2) needs to processXML fragments. With the route as below writing the required java code was easy.

Answer (score 0):

For what I needed, custom beans did the job well. The only thing I had to figure out was how to restore the message to the original content. I guess there is a more elegant way of doing it but works fine:

```
from("cxf:bean:submitOrder")
    .setProperty("originalData", simple("${in.body}")) //save original input msg
    .to("xslt:my.xsl").beanRef("customBean1)
    .setBody(simple("${property.originalData}"))       //restore original message
    .beanRef("customBean2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Wire Tap](http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html) pattern. This pattern allows you to route messages to a separate location while they are being forwarded to the ultimate destination:

```
from("cxf:bean:submitOrder")
    .wireTap("direct:tap")
    .beanRef("customBean2");

from("direct:tap")
    .to("xslt:my.xsl")
    .beanRef("customBean1);
```